# suppose we have a collection $F$ and a countable subcollection $G$ of $F$. suppose $\sigma(G)$ is the sigma algebra generated by $G$. prove:

Tags: measure-theory

suppose we have a collection $F$ and a countable subcollection $G$ of $F$. suppose $\sigma(G)$ is the sigma algebra generated by $G$. prove the following statement:

the union of all sigma algebra's generated by countable sub-collections of F is again a sigma algebra.

i) $X \in \sigma(G) \space \forall G \subset  F \text{ and } \#G = \#\mathbb{N}$. So in particular $X \in \cup \sigma(G)$.

ii) suppose $A \in \cup \sigma(G)$. Is it true that $A^c \in \cup \sigma(G)$?

If all countable subsets G of F are disjoint this is obviously true. I don't see how this is true when A is in a union of sigma algebra's where the intersection is not empty.

iii) Suppose $A_i \in \cup \sigma(G)$, then $\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} A_i \in \cup \sigma(G)$?.

Suppose $A_i \in \cup \sigma(G_i)$, where $G_i$ is a countably subset of $F$. Then we see that $\cup A_i \in \cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \cup \sigma(G_i)$. I know one can't say that $\cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \cup \sigma(G_i) = \cup \sigma(\cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} G_i)$. So i get kind of stuck here too.

any tips or hints to solve ii, iii ?

Kees

Comment: (ii) Since $A \in \cup \sigma(G)$ then $A$ is at least in some $\sigma$-algebra. What does this say about its complement?

Comment: then it's complement is in the same sigma algebra, but suppose A is exact in the intersection of two sigma algebra's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (ii) note the following: If $A \in \bigcup_G \sigma(G)$, then - by the definition of the union - you have $A \in \sigma(G)$ for some countable $G \subseteq F$ (you do not care if $A$ is in one or more of these $\sigma$-algebras, in their intersection, it just does not matter), hence, as $\sigma(G)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $A^c \in \sigma(G)$, therefore - by definition of the union - $A^c \in \bigcup_G \sigma(G)$.

For (iii) suppose, $A_i \in \bigcup_G \sigma(G)$ are given for $i \in \mathbf N$. Choose, as above, countable $G_i\subseteq F$ with $A_i \in \sigma(G_i)$. As the countable union of countable sets is countable, $G := \bigcup_i G_i$ is a countable subset of $F$. Moreover, we have for $i \in \mathbf N$: 
$$ A_i \in \sigma(G_i) \subseteq \sigma(G) $$
as $\sigma(G)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, therefore $\bigcup_i A_i \in \sigma(G)$. Hence $\bigcup_i A_i \in \bigcup_G \sigma(G)$.